# A C function int firstBitEqualsLast(int x) which returns 1 if bit_0 equals bit_31 and returns 0 otherwise

Tags: c, bit, bitwise-operators

Legal operators
! ~ & ^ | << >>

I have tried this code:

```
int lhs = ((x << 31)>>31);
int rhs = (x >> 31);
return (~(lhs ^ rhs));
```

But output was not always as expected

Comment: Why not just `int lhs = x & 1;`?

Comment: Try using `unsigned` variables to be more certain what happens with all that shifting. Anyway shouldn't the shifts be `31`?

Comment: What if an `int` is only 16 bits?  `int` does not have to be 32 bits.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have used 31, it was just a typo

Comment: Welcome! Always try to copy/paste actual code that you have compiled and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't know of any data type whose MSB is bit 30. However, 32- bit `int`s have their MSB in bit 31, so you might try using that value instead.
2. You should always use `unsigned` types when performing bit operations.

   ```
   #include <stdint.h>

   uint32_t lsb = ((uint32_t)(value & 1));
   uint32_t msb = ((uint32_t)((value >> 31) & 1));

   return !(msb ^ lsb);
   ```